# Installing Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, hp, hp-proliant

Just wondering if someone could help with the following. I have a HP Proliant DL140 Server and wanted to install Win Server 2008; however, during Windows installation it cannot see the HD and I have no disks and or floppy facility to install drivers etc - therefore I though about installing Hyper-v on this machine.

I have downloaded Hyper-V, but I see it needs to be installed ontop of a OS and then I assume Hyper-v is installed and from there I can create the virtual machines. Being that no Win Server disk will work and that only Win 7 is fine to install on this does anyone have any recommendations on the way forward?

Answer (score 6):

Try getting a current version (2008 is outdated - 2008R2 is the current version).

Then get the drivers for your hardware and load them during windows install (yes, there is a load driver button there, right where you see no hard discs).

Answer (score 5):

Windows 2008 will let us use storage drivers on a USB drive and all DL-140's have USB ports. Go to HP's web site and download the drivers you need and during the install process you can tell the installer to look at your USB drive.

http://www8.hp.com/us/en/support-drivers.html

Answer (score 1):

What version of HyperV did you download? HyperV comes in two flavours - a plugin/feature for windows 2008 and higher, and a dedicated stand-alone server.

It sounds like you've downloaded the [hyperv feature for Windows 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950050) rather than *HyperV server* itself.

Try downloading Microsoft HyperV Server 2008r2 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/hyper-v-server/en/us/r2.aspx).

As an aside, hyperV server may still not see all your server hardware if it doesn't have the right drivers. Can you not get a HP Server ["smartstart"/insight foundation](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/core-management-100.html) (or whatever its called this week) install pack? This should work for Windows, too.